# Multi-column values in gem5 stats

Tags: gem5

gem5 stats include some lines with multiple value columns. 
How should we understand them?

**For example:**

The following line is very intuitive and self-explanatory.

```
system.cpu.itb.wrAccesses  761786015  # TLB accesses on write requests
```

However, the following lines have more than one value columns.

```
system.cpu.iq.fu_full::MemRead      165768608 93.48%   93.49% # attempts to use FU when none available
system.cpu.iq.fu_full::MemWrite         43109  0.02%   93.52% # attempts to use FU when none available
system.cpu.iq.fu_full::FloatMemRead  11493101  6.48%  100.00% # attempts to use FU when none available
```

In my understanding, the first value (`11493101`) is the absolute number of `attempts to use FloatMemRead unit when none available`, which is `6.48%` of the `attempts to use all units when none available`. The last column seems like the cumulative distribution of `attempts to use an FU when none available`. Is that correct?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I would also grep the source code and see if it is easy to understand from there, then mention in the question what you've found :-)